# How to change the draggable icon of new theme

Tags: 7, forms

I am using draggable table in my new theme. Every thing is working properly but

I want to show this icon like in Bartik theme for every draggable rows:-

[image]

Currently it is showing as

[image]

How to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's similar to a problem I had with draggable table rows in a zen subtheme: the icon was just a bit mis-placed. Using Firebug or similar tools you can see what's going on – on my site it looked like this:

[image]

Using firebug I could see the reason for this:

[image]

The icon was mis-placed. So I suppose you probably don't have to *change the draggable icon* itself, but you'll have to *adjust the position* of the icon.

The css responsible for the position should look like this:

```
a.tabledrag-handle .handle {
background: url("../../misc/draggable.png") no-repeat scroll 6px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
height: 13px;
margin: -0.4em 0.5em;
padding: 0.42em 0.5em;
width: 13px;
}
```

and you should find it in this system css file:
/modules/system/system.base.css

Instead of changing it in that system css file you should however override the settings in your theme's css file. You probably don't have to change much – just have to play around with the settings for margin and padding according to your theme… Hope this helps somehow?

Comment: You Rock Man!! Thanks for pointing me in right direction. After playing around I get my icon as desired. Thanks for help again.